# How to find the image, rank, null space and nullity of the linear operator $D(p) := \dfrac{d}{dt}p(t).$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$:

$$V = \mathbb{R}[t] = \big\{p(t) = a_0 + a_1t + \ldots + a_nt^n\,\big|a_j \in\mathbb{R}\big\}\,.$$

of all the real polynomial  with real coefficients, with degree at most $n< \infty$.

> a)  Find the image, rank, null space and nullity of the linear transformation 
>    defined by the linear operator: $D(p) := \dfrac{d}{dt}p(t).$

Image: $\left\{\dfrac{d}{dt}p(t) = a_1 + 2a_2t + \ldots+ na_nt^{n-1}\,\Big|\,a_i \in\mathbb{R}\right\}$.

Rank: $n-1$.

Null space: All constant polynomials, i.e $p(t)=a_0$.

Nullity: $1$.

> b) If $T : V \to V$ is the linear operator defined as $T\big(p(t)\big):=t\cdot p(t)$, then prove that $$D\circ T−T\circ D=\text{Id}_V$$ and conclude $D\circ T\neq T\circ D$.

$$D\circ T\big(p(t)\big)=D(a_0t+a_1t^2+\ldots+a_nt^{n+1})=a_0+2a_1t+\ldots+(n+q)a_nt^n$$

$$T\circ D\big(p(t)\big) = T(a_1+2a_2t+\ldots+na_nt^{n-1})=a_1t+2a_2t^2+\ldots+na_nt^n$$

Therefore,
$$\begin{align} (D\circ T-T \circ D)(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\ldots+a_nt^n &=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\ldots+a_nt^n)\\&= \text{Id}_V(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\ldots+a_nt^n)\,,\end{align}$$
so $D\circ T-T\circ D=\text{Id}_V$.

And as $D\circ T-T\circ D\neq 0$, we have $D\circ T\neq T\circ D$.

I think part (b) is right, but I would like to have some help with the part (a).

Answer (score 1):

In part b., the $n$ is not considered fixed, i.e. $V=\Bbb R[t]$, the full polynomial space, else $T$ would lead out of $V$.

However, your thoughts on part a. work only with fixed max. degree $n$.
But that already shows that every polynomial of degree $\le n-1$ is in the image of $D$, hence *all* polynomials are in the image, the rank is thus infinite.

The nullity and null space are correct.